# Cannot get resource from android application

Tags: android, resources

I am building an Android app, and I have a problem to get resource from string.xml.

I need to have a URL in `String.xml` that will be used several times through the app.

I tried `Resources.getText("my_url")`, but this does not work. Eclipse complains when I use this.

Do you think this is the best way to do ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you probably want is:

```
String myUrl = getString(R.string.my_url);
```

The [`getString()` method is in `Context`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) which means that it's available directly in your `Activity` class since `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`.  (The `getString()` method is also in `Resources` but it's easier to call on it directly on your `Activity`.)

What happens with your XML resources is that each is given a unique integer ID and this is added to the [automatically generated `R` class](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#UsingResources) as a `public static final int`.  You then use these IDs to reference the resources.  Have a look in the `gen` folder in your Eclipse project and you'll find the `R` class in there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this. But, If I want to get this string outside an Activity (in a helper classe for instance), can I use a GetBaseContext().getString(key) ?

Comment: I have no idea what `GetBaseContext()` is I'm afraid.  I pass a `Context` to each of my help classes to allow them to do things like this.  However, be careful when you to this as if you hang on to a reference to the Context you can leak memory rather badly.  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point and a very good article. Cheers, Luc

Comment: Hello, I do not have any complain from eclipse when I use:
server = context.getString(R.string.server_url);
So, this seems good. The problem I might have is linked to the leak for context ref (as you pointed out in the article). Do you think this is safe to have a private context in an activity (instantiate with context = this in the onCreate method) and pass this context to the Utilities methods ?
Thanks a lot,
Luc

Comment: Passing the `Context` to the Utility methods is fine, just make sure none of the Utility classes hold on to a reference to the `Content`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever refer this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html ?

If you want to retrieve the String represented by a resource ID, you can call the `Context.getString()` method.

Or, you have to post Eclipse's complains.